# How to create a relation between 2 documents in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Ruby on Rails application that usually communicates with MongoDB through the `Mongoid` gem, but for performance reasons I need to insert documents directly into MongoDB like this:

```
Order.collection.insert(Array.new << {order_id: order_id, mail_address: mail_address}) # this creates the document, but does not return anything useful that can be referenced: {"n"=>0, "connectionId"=>53675, "wtime"=>0, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}

Customer.collection.insert(Array.new << {mail_address: mail_address})
```

I have defined a relationshop where a `Customer` has many `Orders`, so if I used Mongoid I could create the relation with `customer.orders << order`.

**But how do I create the relation when I'm not using Mongoid?**

Comment: Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26921118/479863) suggests that you've figured this out (at least mostly), do you still have a question here?

Comment: Thanks for digging into this question. You've been a live saver a few times now. My issue here still exists. Basically, when I use the above method to create objects I don't get a `_id` back. The response from the creation is `{"n"=>0, "connectionId"=>53675, "wtime"=>0, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}`. So when I have created the first object, then I don't know how to reference it when I create the second object.

Comment: A solution could be to start setting the `_id` attributes myself (`field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ my_attribute }`), and then set `my_attribute` to a string like e.g. `"customer_#{mail_address}"` and `"order_#{order_id}"`. Then I will know the `_id`'s to reference. But it feels like a quite ugly solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of Moped's `insert` methods return anything terribly useful to you so your documents are getting normal ObjectId's in their `_id` but you have no easy way of knowing what they are. You're on the right track by trying to assign your own `_id`s but you don't have to use `String`s, you can simply say `Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new` to generate a new `_id`. Assuming that your `Order`s have a `customer_id` which points at the `Customer`, you could:

```
customer_id = Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new
Customer.collection.insert(_id: customer_id, mail_address: mail_address)
Order.collection.insert(customer_id: customer_id, ...)
```

Don't be afraid to poke around inside MongoDB using the `mongo` shell to see how things are structured internally. All the helpful relations and embedding conveniences that Mongoid provides are nice but you still need to know what they're doing to your database.