# MongoDB creates parent objects when I try to create child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

This model:

```
class SimCustomer < Customer
  index({ user_id: 1 },       { background: true })
  belongs_to :user,           :inverse_of => :sim_customers
end
```

inherits from this model:

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :mail_address,        type: String
end
```

I create the indexes from my terminal:

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

But this creates indexes on the `Customer` instead of the `SimCustomer`:

```
I, [2014-11-13T16:21:17.210343 #11407]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Customer:
I, [2014-11-13T16:21:17.210381 #11407]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:user_id=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
```

And when I try to batch insert `SimCustomer` objects it creates `Customer` objects instead:

```
SimCustomer.collection.insert(Array.new << {mail_address: "hello@hello.com", user_id: "54652f5b43687229b4060000"})
# => #<Customer _id: 54654b7b6220ff4f28364ee9, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, mail_address: "hello@hello.com", _type: "Customer">
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sets up Single Collection Inheritance:

```
class SimCustomer < Customer
```

That means that both `Customer` and `SimCustomer` will be stored in the `customers` collection inside MongoDB and they'll be differentiated using the `_type` field.

Specifying an index in `SimCustomer`:

```
class SimCustomer < Customer
  index({ user_id: 1 },       { background: true })
```

will create the index on the `customers` collection because that's where `SimCustomer`s are stored.

The same collection chicanery is causing your problem with your bulk insert. If you look at `SimCustomer.collection.name` you'll find that it says `'customers'` so of course `SimCustomer.collection.insert` will create new `Customer`s. If you want to create `SimCustomer`s by hand then specify the `_type`:

```
SimCustomer.collection.insert(
  _type: 'SimCustomer',
  mail_address: "hello@hello.com",
  user_id: "54652f5b43687229b4060000"
)
```

Note that I dropped that strange looking `Array.new <<` stuff, I don't know where you learned that from but it is unnecessary when inserting on object and odd looking if you were inserting several, if you want to insert several then just use an array literal:

```
SimCustomer.collection.insert([
  { ... },
  { ... },
  ...
])
```

Your next problem is going to be that string in `user_id`. That really should be a `Moped::BSON::ObjectId` or you'll end up with a string inside the database and that will make a mess of your queries. Mongoid may know what type a property should be but neither Moped nor MongoDB will. You'll want to use `Moped::BSON::ObjectId('54652f5b43687229b4060000')` instead.

Comment: Thanks ever so much! And yes, don't know why I put in an array when inserting.